# ImageMagick: turn pdf into png, with a transparent background

Tags: imagemagick

I've a pdf, and I'd like to turn it into a png with the background set to transparent. I tried to do `convert -density 300 "in.pdf" -resize 1920x1080 -channel rgba -transparent white "out.png"`, unfortunately it is not a great solution as it turns all white to transparent (including white texts), and does not handle properly the gradients:

[image]

Any idea how to make it work?

**EDIT**

So I produced this file using beamer... but it seems that beamer adds a white image behind, as with other file produced without beamer I don't have this issue, by default there is no background... If someone knows how to remove the background in beamer, please let me know ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in fact beamer added automatically a white background in the pdf. To remove it, I needed to use `\usebackgroundtemplate{}` before my slides. Then, by default convert will insert a transparent background.